# How do we set border-top-radius 50% without diminishing the border edges?

Tags: css

I would like to have the same border width px throughout the half circle.

Please refer to the image attachment below:

[image]

```css
#loader-frame {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  border-top: 3px solid #3498db;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="loader-frame"></div>
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: There are pages where you can get work done.... toptal.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make two sides of the `border-*-color` `transparent` and use the `transform: rotate()` to *align* it *horizontally*:

```css
#loader-frame {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #3498db; /* modified */
  display: flex;
  /*flex-flow: row nowrap; by default*/
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* added */
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="loader-frame"></div>
```